# Switched Asp.Net MVC app authentication from windows to forms but still allows windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

As per Subject I am trying to change an existing asp.net mvc web app to use forms authentication instead of windows.  So far I have done the following:

- Modified authentication mode in web.config
- Added Authorize tag to all controllers (except Account)
- Created new controller for Login View, the view, model, etc.

web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Login Post:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Login model, string ReturnUrl = "")
    {
        // code to check user omitted
        if(user != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username and/or Password is incorrect.");
        ModelState.Remove("Password");
        return View();
    }
```

When debugging, the login screen is produced by default and not Home/Index. If I test the different usernames/passwords everything is working correctly so no issues with the controller/methods here.

However on Home/Index I put the following for testing:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <p>Logged in @ViewBag.ClientName</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>Logged off</p>
    }
```

The ViewBag.ClientName is just set from User.Identity.Name.
When I login normally the ClientName shows my pc name/local user and not the forms user I logged in with.  I can also browse directly to Index/Home and ignore the login to get the same result.

Clearly Windows authentication is still applying here and I have tried closing IIS Express, changing the URL it debugs at etc in case its some form of IIS setting or similar still being set on my local machine but I can't stop this from happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer but just in case this helps anyone else out the answer was really simple.

Click on Project in Solution Explorer window. Press F4 to see settings if window not open already and there is a Windows Authentication option there which I had to switch off.